# problem with plugin in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn-model, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i was trying to spawn again a urdf model that I spawned a lot allready but today it isn't recognizing the plugin

any ideas?
the plugin that is doing it-

```
<gazebo>
    <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
      <interface:audio name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager_dummy_iface" />
   </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
  </gazebo>
```

**edit5:** I made a different urdf file and it wasn't willing to spawn it either.

can i get this plugin to work a different way?

Thanks

yesterday it did work fine

**edit4:** I reinstalled  all of ros and it still **isn't** spawning
i am getting this message--
Dbg plugin model name: bob

```
[ INFO] [1347535810.546163240, 391.723000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1347535810.546328843, 391.723000000]: Callback thread id=0x7f2a0c10f010
```

How should i get it to work??

the error is

```
Error [Plugin.hh:101] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**edit1:** i was able to copy that file into the directory, somehow i have two directories of  pr2_gazebo_plugins. now it doesn't say it can't find the plugin, just writes -- loading model xml from file

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1347451924.654210] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
```

w/o nothing happening.
am I missing files? (gazebo spawns other models like pr2 etc.)

**edit2:**
If I first did --roslaunch pr2_examples_gazebo single_link.launch-- then exited and then again launched gazebo, it was able to spawn the model but the topic about joint states thought that my joint was the same as the single link model.

**edit3:** I did these commands--

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-fuerte-pr2-simulator
```

and the same thing happened, the model is not spawned.

Thanks

Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43578/problem-with-plugin-in-gazebo/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so` does not exist in

```
ls `rospack find pr2_gazebo_plugins`/lib
```

then you need to compile the plugins:

```
rosmake pr2_gazebo_plugins
```

Alternatively, if you installed from deb, do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-fuerte-pr2-simulator
```

---

If the debian installed version runs correctly, you might want to remove your local copy of `pr2_simulator` path from `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

Is there a reason you want to check out `pr2_simulator` locally and compile from source?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-11**:
I guess it finds it, I mean nothing happens. if I change a bit the name i get an error [rospack] Error: stack/package pr2_gazebo_plugin not found. i also am able to roscd into pr2_gazebo_plugins

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-11**:
It finds it but can't see what is inside. if i wrote - ls `rospack find pr2_gazebo_plugins`/src - so it gave me the files inside but with ls `rospack find pr2_gazebo_plugins`/lib- it didn't show a thing. how can i fix it? Thanks

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-09-12**:
Try: rosmake pr2_gazebo_plugins

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-12**:
this is what i get when doing it -  Built 71 packages with 1 failures.

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-09-12**:
Which platform you are on? Ubuntu?

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-12**:
I am on ubunto 12.04